# Removing back slash from html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, email

i've problem when removing backslash from html on NODE JS

Code :

```
var html = <html style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; transition: .5s all;\">
```

That i want is :

```
var html = <html style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; transition: .5s all;">
```

I have tried :

```
html = html.replace(/\\/g, '') 

html = html.replace(/\"/g, '"')
```

but still can't replaced. how to removed this backslash from my html email?

Comment: Your html variable is not a string!

Comment: so, what must i do?

Comment: ...put it in a string I guess ?

Comment: @agungdev add double quotes to the var html in the beginning and at the end

Comment: i adding ' ` ' on my var html, this is problem?

Comment: Use a backslash on the \\` to get a \` in SO comments

Comment: Add double quotes to your variable and then if you use replace, it  will work and you will get the string without backslash

Comment: for replace i think there's no problem when we using '`' i've tried.

Comment: but if we want to build html email on node js can i using double quotes for this?

Comment: Both double and reversed work

Comment: https://prnt.sc/mwtk1j

this is my code, any wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what do you whant to achive, but in my opinion you are on a wrong path. Anyway you can try this:

```
var html = `<html style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; transition: .5s all;">`;
```

Good luck!

Comment: i've been tried this. but i will get "<html style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; transition: .5s all;\">"

like the question above, that i want just removing the backslash

Comment: you only get this if you JSON.stringify it

Comment: @agung dev Wrapping your html with double quotes or reversed quotes will work so his answer is correct

Comment: i've been tried this.

look at my code : https://prnt.sc/mwtk1j

any wrong?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/mwtzhb just look if i using double quotes for build this html
we can got error. how to solved it?